# is it possible to integrate Refiner CMS into my pre existing Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I am working in a Rails application, is it possible to integrate Refiner CMS into my pre existing Rails application? if not do i have to create a Refinery project and then integrate my application with it?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that should be fine.

Refinery is just a gem. So you can include it in your existing project and run the specific generators you need if you are not already running Devise.

Comment: I am already running Devise gem in my application (Version : 2.1.0)
Will this version conflict with devise used by Refinery..?

Comment: yes it will I am running into issues with the conflict now. as far as I can tell following this http://www.synaptian.com/blogs/integrating-refinery-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-rails-app tutorial is the only solution